# Bad request error replicating a python request on JS

Tags: javascript, python, flask, fetch

I'm working on an app which backend is in python, for that I'm using flask and swagger.

From python I make the request as:

```
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
data = {}
url = 'http://SERVERIP:5100/api/generatate_response'
resp = requests.post(url,data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers )

r =  (json.loads(resp.text))
```

And get the response:

```
{'status': 'OK'}
```

Now I'm trying to do the same from JS using fetch:

```
let data = {
    name: 'John',
    surname: 'Smith'
  };


function sentData () {
    fetch("http://SERVERIP:5100/api/generatate_response", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      }


)
    .then( function(res) {
        return res.json()
    })
    .then(function(data)  {
        console.log(data)
    } )
```

}

But I get the following error:

```
VM220:2 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk03JfQaAaOO7vKNvyv6lmE8E2OB7qg%3A1589647482208&ei=ehjAXoylDLvW5OUP-rC2oA0&q=err_ssl_protocol_error+stack+overflow&oq=ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR+stack&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgAMgUIABDLATIGCAAQFhAeOgQIABBHOgQIABBDOgIIADoHCAAQFBCHAlDzNFinO2CERWgAcAF4AIABa4gBpwOSAQM1LjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://52.170.1.84:5100/api/generatate_response'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
sentData @ VM220:2
(anonymous) @ VM242:1
```

I'm doing this from the chrome console:

[image]

Then I tried the same just changing the url from http to https:

And got this other error:

```
VM258:2 POST https://SERVERIP:5100/api/generatate_response net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
sentData @ VM258:2
(anonymous) @ VM263:1
```

And from the server side:

```
xxx - - [16/May/2020 16:57:12] code 400, message Bad request version ('"\x00"ÊÊ\x13\x01\x13\x02\x13\x03À+À/À,À0Ì©Ì¨À\x13À\x14\x00\x9c\x00\x9d\x00/\x005\x00')
xxx - - [16/May/2020 16:57:12] "  üGWÁ`'§=ñu,åZúCÊïÄ½LEÑÐ_}ßë %eFª zûjOqÐéÝ'émºN@%RÄ" "ÊÊÀ+À/À,À0Ì©Ì¨ÀÀ   / 5 " HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST -
```

The mehod that is been called on the server side is:

```
def generatate_response(documents):
    """
    """

    print ("request received")

    result = {"status":"OK"}
    return result
```

Comment: As the error message states, you're sending a request to http endpoint from https origin - so it fails. Try replacing `http://` with `https://`

Comment: @SidVishnoi I did that, last error is from trying it: code 400, message Bad request